# higer order component not displayed correctly

Tags: reactjs

I m following tutorials to learn the concept of Hocs in `React js` the result of the tutorial should display in My browser like this :

```
toolbar,sideDrawer,backdrop
Burger
Build Controls
```

but it displayed like this :

```
toolbar,sideDrawer,backdrop
```

I cleaned cache in both browser and development server but nothing happened...so please any help or guide why this??Thanks in advance

**Aux.js**

```
const Aux = (props) =>  props.children

export default Aux;
```

**Layout.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Aux from '../../hoc/Aux';
import classes from './Layout.css'
const Layout = ( props ) => (
        <Aux>
        <div>toolbar,sideDrawer,backdrop</div>
        <main className={classes.Content}>
        {props.childern}
        </main>
        </Aux>
);

export default Layout;
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Layout from './components/Layout/Layout'
import BuliderBurger from './containers/BurgerBuilder/BurgerBuilder';


class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Layout>
          <BuliderBurger/>
        </Layout>
      </div> 
    );
  }   
}

export default App;
```

**BurgerBuilder.js**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Aux from '../../hoc/Aux';

class BurgerBuilder extends Component { 
    render () {
        return (
         <Aux>
         <div>Burger</div>
         <div>Build Controls</div>
         </Aux>
        );
    }
}


export default BurgerBuilder;
```

Comment: What browser are you using for your tests? `main` is not supported in any version of IE

Comment: @DanielHilgarth im using chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you misspelt `children` in `Layout`, you spellt it `childern`. Fix the typo and it works...

```
const Layout = ( props ) => (
    <Aux>
    <div>toolbar,sideDrawer,backdrop</div>
    <main className={classes.Content}>
    {props.children}
    </main>
    </Aux>
);
```

Comment: Yes.. sorry I didn't see your answer.. Just saw it.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth  why both of them worked the first answer didnt suggested the misspelt and it worked..any explain .. im novice in react

Comment: It's just a coincidence. The resulting DOMs are different. Fix the bug as per my answer and then use the code from the other answer. You will see that you are now seeing the Burger code twice. Once from inside the Layout component and once *below* the layout component.

Answer (score -1):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Layout from './components/Layout/Layout'
import BuliderBurger from './containers/BurgerBuilder/BurgerBuilder';


class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Layout/>
        <BuliderBurger/>
      </div> 
    );
  }   
}

export default App;
```

Using **Layout** this can give the desired result

Comment: This is something else entirely

Comment: @Rajan Lagah your suggestion worked...but could you explain the difference between i mean why your solution worked..and tut guy not worked...don't worry i will accept your answer..thanks Sir.

Comment: @ALTegani: That's not the solution you want, because it doesn't fix the error you made. It just circumvents it somehow.

Comment: @yes circumvents... what Confusing me why that??

Comment: My Apology. But, I was not able to test my ans, so this came to my mind.